# How to call another controller on long press of UITableViewCell in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uilongpressgesturerecogni

I am using the below code to display `MyEditViewController` but all the field outlets in `MyEditViewController` are **nil** because of this line `let editController = MyEditViewController()`. Here I am creating new instance. So outlets are **nil** now. Is there any other way to call the edit controller without creating instance of it?

```
@IBAction func editMethod(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
        if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began {
            let cell = sender.view as! MyTableViewCell
            let editController = MyEditViewController()
            editController.sample= samples[cell.tag]
            presentViewController(editController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you already have an instance of it created?  (If so, what has a reference to it?)

Comment: How have you defined `MyEditViewController`? Is it's layout in a storyboard or a xib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To instantiate a new controller with your outlets you can use a xib

```
let editController = MyEditViewController(nibName: "MyEditViewController", bundle: nil)
```

Or you can attribute a StoryboardId to your controller and use with instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier

```
let editController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MyEditViewControllerStoryboardId") as! MyEditViewController
```

Or as a suggestion for your case, you can use a different approach using storyboard segues. [Read more about it here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/UsingSegues.html)

```
performSegueWithIdentifier("PresentMyEditController", sender: self)
```

Comment: The 2nd solution is working fine but in`MyEditViewController` screen, I am not getting the navigation bar.

Comment: That's because you are instantiating a normal UIViewController instead of a UINavigationController.

You can create a navigation with:

    let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: editController)

and then

    presentViewController(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)

Answer (score 1):

You should initiate not a Class, you shoud initiate it as an ViewController from Storyboard. So in your case set an "Storyboard-ID" for your Controller.

[image]

And then use:

```
    let editController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("StoryboardID") as! MyEditViewController
```

So all outlets should work fine.

Comment: I tried your solution it is working fine but in`MyEditViewController` screen, I am not getting the navigation bar.

Comment: self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true